# Determining if Spreadsheet Entries Match Database Column Entries

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access-2007, vba

One aspect of my project involves comparing the part number entered by the operator to a predetermined list of part numbers in a column in a database.  Right now, my program is telling me that every part number entered in the spreadsheet (50+) does not match any in the database, which I've verified to be incorrect.  I've checked that both the spreadsheet part number and the database part number are of string datatype.  I've doublechecked that my looping logic is good, and to me seems like it should work.  To the best of my knowledge there are no hidden characters in either the database cells or in the spreadsheet cells.  I'm completely stumped at this point as to why my program doesn't detect any matches between the spreadsheet and the database.  Below is the Sub containing the code for checking that the part numbers match:

```
Sub CheckPN()
  'Connect to the E2 database
   Call SetPNConnection
  'Open a recordset
   Set PNRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
   PNRecordset.Open "EstimRpt", PNConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
   PNSQLCmd = "SELECT DISTINCT [PartNo] FROM EstimRpt;"
  'Loop through data, comparing part numbers to E2 database part number records
   TotalBadPNCount = 0
   With PNRecordset
      For DataRowCount = 2 To TrackingLastRow
         PNCount = 0
         Part_Number = Tracking.Sheets("Operator Data").Range("A" & DataRowCount).Value
        'MsgBox "The datatype for " & Part_Number & " is " & VarType(Part_Number) & "."
         Do Until .EOF
           'MsgBox "The datatype for " & .Fields("PartNo").Value & " is " & VarType(.Fields("PartNo").Value) & "."
            If Part_Number = .Fields("PartNo").Value Then
           'If .Fields("PartNo").Value = Part_Number Then
               MsgBox Part_Number & " is a match."
               PNCount = PNCount + 1
            End If
            .MoveNext
         Loop
         If PNCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "The P/N " & Part_Number & " entered in cell A" & DataRowCount & " is incorrect.  Please correctly enter the P/N and re-run the program."
            TotalBadPNCount = TotalBadPNCount + 1
         End If
      Next DataRowCount
      If TotalBadPNCount >= 1 Then
         Exit Sub
      End If
   End With
   PNRecordset.Close
   Set PNRecordset = Nothing
   PNConnection.Close
   Set PNConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

On a side note, I'd like to have the entire program stop executing if a part number doesn't match, not just the immediate sub.  Currently, just this sub exits upon no part number matches.

Thanks for the help on both of these issues.

Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using a loop to compare records from your user-submitted dataset to your permanent table. Instead, load the user-submitted dataset into a temporary table in your DB, and use SQL to compare the 2 tables.

You can try something along these lines:

```
'Load spreadsheet into temp table
<your code here>

'open recordset in order to compare PartNos
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As Recordset

sSQL = "select count(*) as [count] from temp " _ 
        & " where temp.PartNo not in (select distinct EstimRpt.PartNo from EstimRpt)"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

ctRecords = rs![Count]

'if records are found in temp table that do not exist 
'in the perm table, then end execution of everything.
if ctRecords > 0 then
    End
else
    'run the rest of your code
    <your code here>
end if

'Drop temp table
<your code here>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why comparing records in my user-submitted Excel dataset to my permanent Access table wouldn't work?  The alternative to going this route seems to be quite cumbersome, relatively speaking.  If both the Access and Excel records are of type string, why don't those that should match, match?  Is there some "hidden" difference between the two records?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't tell why your current comparison is not working without having access to your files. If any compatibility issues exist between the versions of Excel / Access, pulling the Excel data into Access before running your comparison will highlight those issues (check the data types of the Excel columns once they've been imported into Access). Once the data is in Access, you can run a set-based comparison without using [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/), which greatly improves performance when you're dealing with large data sets.

Comment: The database from which I'm reading is one in which it's imperative I don't change/alter/modify in any way (it's a sizeable database used for a shop management program).  Therefore, I only want to read data from it and not anything else.  So, ruling that out, I've again made sure both values are strings and, according to message boxes in my excel program, my excel program is reading/interpreting the database values exactly as they are written in Excel.  This seems to indicate that my data is good but that my looping is flawed but it looks good to me.  Ant suggestions?

Comment: Ok - good luck! I can't suggest anything because I can't see what is actually going on 'under the hood' in your Excel & Access files. If you don't want to create any new objects in the existing Access DB, you can create a separate DB that pulls data from the 'main' one and do the comparison in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem at long last.  The comparing records between database and spreadsheet does work now.  I had to make the following changes to my code:

Instead of:

```
Do Until .EOF
```

I needed:

```
Do Until .EOF = True
```

I also needed to add the following just after the For Loop declaration:

```
.MoveFirst
```

Now my code loops correctly.